# Pushing docker image to new docker hub account fails

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I need to change the Docker Hub account that I'm pushing my images to. I used `docker login` to update my `.dockercfg` file then ran the following (`account`, `image`, and `tag` acting as generic placeholders for my actual values):

`docker push account/image:tag`

I immediately get the following error:

```
The push refers to a repository [account/image] (len: 1)
Sending image list
2014/12/11 21:26:59 Error: Status 400 trying to push repository repo/image:
"Access denied: <hash> is a private image" docker push account/image:tag
returned exit code 1action docker push repo/image:tag failed
```

I am attempting to push to a private repository on docker hub but I've double checked that my auth matches up. Why is this failing and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't fully understand why this happened but I figured out how to fix it. I destroyed all images and containers on my local machine and rebuilt the image. After I did that I was able to push to the new account.

My theory is that the Docker image I originally created depended on layers that had existed in previous builds and that the old account had available. Once I switched to the new account I was trying to push an image that depended on layers that no longer existed in Docker Hub, resulting in that layer not being found, which caused Docker Hub to think the thing I was trying to access must be private, when it actually just didn't exist.

All of the above is pretty much pure conjecture so I'd be delighted to be enlightened by someone with more knowledge and/or experience in this area.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and the reason turned out to be a private parent image. As it is explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/terms/image/), your image is build on top of a base image and in most cases parent images. When you try to push your latest changes into docker hub, your account should have access to all parent images otherwise it results in this error. In my case the user I tried to push with didn't have access to the image I used as a base.

You can easily identify the private image by its hash.

```
docker images -a | grep <hash>
```

If you have access to the private repository you can fix this by adding the user you are pushing with to the list of collaborators.
If you don't however, you will have to tag the private repository for your user and apply apply the rest of the changes manually.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same problem here. In my case, I had in my Dockerfile the instruction "FROM ubuntu:latest". In this case, I had build the image using my old account and to this, I had downloaded the ubuntu:latest to create it, but this download was done using my previous account, so, I just removed the ubuntu:latest (that was the base image used) from my computer and built my image again. After this, I was able to push my image.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well, and Bruno's comment seemed to fix it.  Here is a quick bash comment for removing your images (this is assuming you have DockerFiles and automation in place to recreate them):
docker images | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi -f

Answer (score 0):

I was using latest Docker, building from ubuntu:trusty when this happened.
Deleting all images didn't help. I changed the parent image tag from trusty to older trusty-20150630.